# How can Ron know that Voldemort was in Slytherin if nobody knows his real identity?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, slytherin

When Ron meets Harry on the Hogwarts Express in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, they have this conversation:

> “What House are your brothers in?” asked Harry.
>
> “Gryffindor,” said Ron. Gloom seemed to be settling on him again. “Mum and Dad were in it, too. I don’t know what they’ll say if I’m not. I don’t suppose Ravenclaw *would* be too bad, but imagine if they put me in Slytherin.”
>
> “That’s the House Vol-, I mean, You-Know-Who was in?”
>
> “Yeah,” said Ron. He flopped back into his seat, looking depressed. 
> <sub>- Harry Potter and the Philosopher’s Stone, Chapter 6 (The Journey from Platform Nine and Three-Quarters)</sub>

So Ron apparently knows Voldemort was in Slytherin. But at the end of *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, it is made clear that Voldemort's real identity as the brilliant (Slytherin) student Tom Riddle is unknown to most - in Dumbledore's own words:

> ‘Very few people know that Lord Voldemort was once called Tom Riddle. I taught him myself, fifty years ago, at Hogwarts. He disappeared after leaving the school … travelled far and wide … sank so deeply into the Dark Arts, consorted with the very worst of our kind, underwent so many dangerous, magical transformations, that when he resurfaced as Lord Voldemort, he was barely recognisable. Hardly anyone connected Lord Voldemort with the clever, handsome boy who was once Head Boy here.’ 
> <sub>- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 18 (Dobby’s Reward)</sub>

So how could Ron (as well as, I guess, most wizards) not know Voldemort's real identity yet know the actual House he was in at Hogwarts?

Comment: "Hardly anyone": Some people recognised who he was and given that the house he was in is likely better food for the rumour mill than that he was some student the latter probably fell to the floor.

Comment: Hagrid knows. Maybe Hagrid is a friend of the Weasley Family?

Comment: Actually, the real question is, how did *Harry* know that?

Comment: @Kevin - Because Hagrid told him - "*‘Better Hufflepuff than Slytherin,’ said Hagrid darkly. ‘There’s not a single witch or wizard who went bad who wasn’t in Slytherin. You-Know-Who was one.’*"

Comment: @Valorum: OK, fine.  How did **Hagrid** know that?  The point is, Ron is only half the conversation.

Comment: @Kevin - Hagrid was at Hogwarts at the same time as Riddle. Being that Hagrid is extremely close to and trusted by Dumbledore, was an original member of the OotP, it stands to reason Hagrid would be among those who know

Comment: @Kevin as Hagrid was at Hogwarts around the same time Voldemort was there (even same year students IIRC), he may have recognized him.

Comment: [Did Hagrid know that Tom Riddle was Voldemort?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180543/did-hagrid-know-that-tom-riddle-was-voldemort?rq=1)

Comment: I don't know your real identity, how do I know you have a Stack Exchange account?

Comment: @Jenayah Pretty sure that he wasn't in the same year actually. I believe Hagrid is younger than Riddle. Could be wrong though but I'm pretty sure Hagrid was expelled in year three and I'm fairly certain it took Riddle five or six years to find the Chamber of Secrets.

Comment: Wouldn't everyone just **assume** that, not even being able to imagine him belonging to any other house?

Comment: It's not at all clear whether or not his identity was well known, or how much of it. It seems that everyone knows he went to Hogwarts, roughly when and which house he was in. Common knowledge. Slytherins seem to be secretly proud of that fact.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22840/4918 Was Voldemort's secret identity always known to the Ministry of Magic? Was it ever secret?

Answer (score 105):

## The Dark Lord himself might have said he was in Slytherin.

When the Dark Lord was at the height of his power, though he might not have wanted to talk much about his father or Muggle heritage, he was proud to be the descendant of Salazar Slytherin. He had been even as Tom Riddle, and though he wanted to be rid of his father’s name, he was quite proud of his relation to Slytherin. He called himself "*Lord Voldemort, heir of Salazar Slytherin*", indicating that he intended to keep the Slytherin connection even after he became Lord Voldemort.

> “Now, Harry, I’m going to teach you a little lesson. Let’s match the powers of Lord Voldemort, heir of Salazar Slytherin, against famous Harry Potter, and the best weapons Dumbledore can give him.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 17 (The Heir of Slytherin)*</sup></sub>

He carried this pride into adulthood as well. When he takes over Hogwarts many years later, he announced that there will be no more houses, only Slytherin.

> “There will be no more Sorting at Hogwarts School,’ said Voldemort. ‘There will be no more houses. The emblem, shield and colours of my noble ancestor, Salazar Slytherin, will suffice for everyone, won’t they, Neville Longbottom?” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 (The Flaw in the Plan)*</sup></sub>

It didn’t seem like the Dark Lord was trying to keep his Hogwarts house secret. Even if he didn’t want the wizarding world knowing that he was once Tom Riddle, he was likely perfectly happy to say he was a Slytherin.

Him saying it himself would explain why people seem so certain about his house, rather than it being treated like a widely believed rumor (like the circumstances of his disappearance, or Harry being thought to be the heir of Slytherin by his classmates). His claim to be the heir of Slytherin and ability to speak Parseltongue would help support the idea he was in Slytherin to anyone who knew of them, but the simplest way that people could seem to know his house is for him to have said it.

Comment: This make sense, although it seems a little unlikely that he would say he was in Slytherin House, rather than that he was the heir of Slytherin.

Comment: **It didn’t seem like the Dark Lord was trying to keep his Hogwarts house secret. Even if he didn’t want the wizarding world knowing that he was once Tom Riddle, he was likely perfectly happy to say he was a Slytherin.** Agree. He was proud of his status. He makes it clear in CoS too that he wanted to finish the work. And didn't he say that the colour of Slytherin will be the only colour (i.e. only Slytherin has a place) in the future - when he and everyone else (but Harry and Narcissa of course!) thought Harry was dead? Ah yes you actually cited that!

Comment: @Pryftan Thanks! :) He was quite proud of his status, so I doubt he’d hide being a Slytherin. He‘d have no reason to hide it. He mentions being the heir of Salazar Slytherin, so he could easily have mentioned that he was in Slytherin house as well. If he did, the rest of the wizarding world would likely presume it was true and not bother to question it, despite not knowing who he used to be. That the Dark Lord wanted to make it the only house in Hogwarts and abolish all others shows he’d have to be proud of the *house* specifically, in addition to his connection to Salazar Slytherin.

Comment: @Bellatrix No, because in *Chamber of Secrets*, it definitely was *not* common knowledge that Voldemort was the heir.

Comment: Voldemort did *what now?!* Spoiler tags, perhaps? :)

Comment: @bertieb Which part would you like spoiler tags on?

Comment: @Bellatrix Thank you for asking. Quite a bit of it is spoiler-y I guess; but especially the bits after the first quote. I have read the first few books so it's touger to say how spoilery the first quote is. I mean, "lets match powers" is a little less concrete than "He took over the school"!

Comment: @bertieb You’re welcome! Okay, I’ve changed it for you. Sorry for accidentally giving you spoilers - I wasn’t trying to spoil anyone. I’ll be honest though, I prefer it without the tags, since now I’ve hidden what I consider my best point. Hopefully you enjoy the rest of the series!

Comment: @Bellatrix No worries, I should have been mindful of what I was reading! Thanks, I'll get around to finishing the series someday...

Comment: @bertieb Thanks! :) You’re welcome - hopefully you won’t see any spoilers until then! When you get to the fifth book you’ll see where my name’s from. ;)

Comment: @Buzz I'm confused: first you say **although it seems a little unlikely that he would say he was in Slytherin House, rather than that he was the heir of Slytherin** and then also say **No, because in Chamber of Secrets, it definitely was not common knowledge that Voldemort was the heir** - so what was the 'no' to specifically? Either way he did tell Harry that he was Heir of Slytherin and he was quite proud of it. But then again we're talking of a memory aren't we? In CoS it's his past self (though present and future too in a sense).

Comment: @Pryftan It appears to be reasonably widely known that Voldemort was in Slytherin House.  It is definitely not well known that he was the heir of Slytherin.

Comment: @Buzz Yes and? I don't think anyone is trying to say that he was as such.

Comment: @bertieb I meant to say this the other day but personally I'd strongly recommend that you don't look at this site or other sites on Harry Potter until you've finished the books. You're only going to run into spoilers and sometimes spoiler warnings don't seem appropriate. Personally I think that Miss Bella added those tags shows just how much she cares about her answers (high quality as always Bella!) because it actually looks really weird and wrong the way it is now...Oh and you'll actually first encounter Bella in book four - although in an unique way.

Comment: @Pryftan I agree it’s a good idea for anyone who hasn’t read Harry Potter to not read websites on it yet, there are a lot of unmarked spoilers. Thanks a lot! :) I’m glad you like my answer! I do care very much about my answers, thanks for noticing “ I very much agree with the spoiler tags making it look weird... I don’t want to spoil anyone but I like my important points being visible. Bella’s in book four but not named yet - a first time reader won’t know it’s her yet, which is why I’d said book five. ;)

Comment: @Miss Bella I could have sworn she was named. Perhaps not though; but it's not by any stretch my favourite fantasy so even though I've reread it recently it could very well be something I glossed over. But yes your answers are high quality - if I could vote up more than once I would! - and it definitely is a shame to have to cover that much of your answer. And it does look extremely odd to say the least. If you're not named until book five though then of course that part of my comment is invalid. I do have this vague memory that she's described but maybe not named indeed.

Comment: Oh and btw I think it'd look a bit better if you were to add some notes above each of the two hidden elements, perhaps leading up to it. How so I'm unsure but it might help it slightly; basically adding how it's relevant to each quote? Maybe not above the first one but possibly below the first if not as I suggest? I'll let you work out how but I feel somehow it would improve it. Maybe something that doesn't reveal exactly what it is but explains why and how the hidden text is relevant? One possibility: don't hide the first quote in some way? It's what he says later that matters? Don't know.

Comment: @Pryftan Thanks a lot, and thanks for your suggestion! :) I’m adding in the text leading up to the hidden quotes. Hopefully it’ll help. I definitely think it improves it. I’m honestly a bit tempted to just uncover everything, though. :P

Comment: @Miss Bella personally I would say it'd look a lot better if you did; it does show how serious you take your time spent - and really everyone should but you definitely do (should often isn't reality after all). You do a fantastic job. The change improves it but the fact is it doesn't flow as nicely when you have it hidden by default - and that rather reduces the quality of your work (though it's an indication of your quality when it still is quite good despite this!).

Comment: @Pryftan Thanks a lot! :) I’ve changed it back now!

Answer (score 63):

I don't think we can exclude the possibility that Ron - and more-or-less everyone, actually - simply *assumed* that he was in Slytherin.  It obviously has a reputation for generating villains.  Recall this statement:

> "‘Better Hufflepuff than Slytherin,’ said Hagrid darkly. ‘There’s not a single witch or wizard who went bad who wasn’t in Slytherin. You-Know-Who was one.’"
>
> <sub>—*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*</sub>

Comment: Hagrid seems fairly certain that the Dark Lord was actually a Slytherin - in fact he’s the first one that Hagrid cites as an evil Slytherin. It seems unlikely that he’d choose someone who everyone just guessed was in Slytherin (if there wasn’t some sort of evidence) as his first example of a bad Slytherin. In addition, he stated it pretty definitively - “You-Know-Who was one” rather than “everyone says You-Know-Who was one”.

Comment: @Bellatrix: Hagrid might not be the most careful scholar.  I don't think his definitive statement is very strong evidence that it's known fact rather than widely believed.  (Not disputing the fact, just the use of Hagrid's phrasing as evidence.  Your answer that this info was Voldy's own statements is the most likely, IMO.)

Comment: Call it semantics if you like but it's in this case possibly presumption rather than assumption. Of course it depends on why and what reasons they felt it; it is certain that Slytherin had an unfair (yes unfair) reputation and so if it was based on that bias then it could be less of a presumption after all. (Funny thing occurred to me just now though: Hagrid trusted Severus and Severus was Slytherin - he was also at Hogwarts in Severus's day so would he have known that he was Slytherin and if so is there more to it than just Slytherin?). What's certain is Hagrid's statement here is false.

Comment: @PeterCordes But the thing is his relationship with Dumbledore. Yes he was biased against Slytherin but I suspect that in this case he had a reason to say Voldemort was Slytherin; that doesn't mean his statement cited here is true but then again he might be rather sore about being expelled by Riddle who he would have known to be Slytherin (and of course Dumbledore suspected Riddle but knew he couldn't do much in the matter with Dippet or anyone else for that matter).

Comment: @Pryftan: Interesting point.  But at that point *Ron* didn't know all those facts about Hagrid's backstory.  Of course at that age Ron (and Harry) would just take Hagrid at his word if either didn't already know that Voldemort was Slytherin.  So people like Hagrid using phrasing like this is actually a very good explanation for 10-year-olds treating it as a known fact, whether it is or not.

Comment: @PeterCordes True. I was more so referring to Hagrid directly and not considering Ron.

Comment: @Pryftan: yeah, so was I until I stepped back and remembered that this question was actually asking about Ron's knowledge, not the reader's knowledge.  I agree with your conclusion that given what we find out later, there's good reason to guess that Hagrid might (at that point) have had better actual knowledge than most people.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yep and fair enough. And the site is whining about extended discussions so I'll stop now.

Comment: Why would everyone assume he was at Hogwarts at all when there are other wizarding schools? Hagrid is an exception since he could have learned this from Dumbledore. It's one thing to see Voldemort proudly declare he is the heir of Slytherin but quite a separate issue to assume he was ever at Hogwarts at all before that information was more widely publicised. So I don't get why "more-or-less everyone would assume this.

Comment: Hagrid also knew Tom Riddle when he studied at Hogwarts. He is clearly more informed than most.

Comment: People just think stuff is true that they actually assumed. All the time. Whenever I actually research some real-life-person that I'm interested in, I find out that the vast quantities of whan "is known" about that person is just wrong. It gets worse the longer ago it is (mostly right about Ghandi, usually bogus about Gallilei, nearly all nonsense about Columbus) so assuming one element as fact about a figure that's ten years ago is unsurprising.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs That might be the majority; or it might be you. As for me it's not the case. That doesn't mean I don't learn more in addition but I'm seldom wrong about something I'm passionate about. Of course I'm also not one to make assumptions and I know fully what I don't know and what I do know; this is something that many have a problem with though. Nevertheless I don't think here it was any assumption on Hagrid's part. He had reasons to know. I'm sure there **might be some bias but remember this: he trusted Severus because Dumbledore did and he knew Severus was Slytherin didn't he?**

Comment: @syntonicC There are only 6 wizarding schools around in the HP universe, and judging from GoF, the part of the world you live in has a significant part in what school you are eligible for. While homeschooling is a thing in-universe, it is considered so rare that we never actually see anyone schooled in this manner despite encountering a bunch of other in-universe rarities, and is literally only ever brought up once (7th book). Voldemort mainly concerned himself with, and operated in, the UK, so it's a natural assumption that's the place he calls home, hence he went to Hogwarts.

Answer (score 15):

### Voldemort was indeed a known Parselmouth

Tom Riddle was a half-blood. The Riddle name did not belong to a known pureblood family. Therefore, Voldemort needed to show that he was great in some way, in order to convince witches and wizards to follow him.

After graduating from Hogwarts and disassociating himself from the Riddle name, he could have publicly flaunted his ability to speak in Parseltongue. This would serve as proof that Voldemort was descended from Salazar Slytherin himself, and provide credibility to his image as the champion of pure-bloods, as Salazar Slytherin was also popularly believed to have hated muggleborns due to the legend of Slytherin's monster being created to purge muggleborns from Hogwarts.

> “It matters,” said Hermione, speaking at last in a hushed voice,
> “because being able to talk to snakes was what Salazar Slytherin was
> famous for. That’s why the symbol of Slytherin House is a serpent.”
>
> <sub>-Hermione Granger, Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets</sub>

Therefore, Ron and the entire wizarding world must have taken Voldemort's status as a Parselmouth as proof that he was descended from Salazar Slytherin.

---

> Parseltongue, the ability to converse with snakes, has long been
> considered a Dark Art. **Indeed, the most famous Parselmouth of our
> times is none other than You-Know-Who himself**.
>
> -<sub>*The Daily Prophet*</sub>
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Page 612</sub>

*This particular quote proves that Voldemort was a known Parselmouth.*

Comment: Is it common knowledge that Parselmouths are direct descendants of the Slytherin bloodline?

Comment: @Slytherincess It may not be common knowledge, but even then, most witches and wizards are prone to jumping to conclusions. The fact that Salazar Slytherin was a world-famous parselmouth helped Voldemort build credibility on his ancestry.

Comment: Wait.  The snake symbol for Slytherin wasn't because his name was *Slytherin*?

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach Little-known fact: the Muggle word 'slither' is derived from Salazar Slytherin's name.

Answer (score 7):

### The Dark Mark

When Voldemort was in power, there were attacks everywhere, and when Death Eaters attack somewhere they cast the Dark Mark, which is Voldemort’s symbol with a snake on it. I think people could make deductions about his house afterwards.

There is citation somewhere in the books about the Dark Mark being seen very frequently at Voldemort’s golden years. If someone finds and edits this answer , It will be a more complete answer.

Answer (score 4):

Dumbledore may have been correct that few people knew Voldemort's identity during his reign of Terror and even afterward.  However, the British wizarding community is too small for it to have been kept a secret in retrospect.  With only a few thousand individuals, it would be relatively straightforward to track down everyone who were still living or confirmed dead after the dark lord's defeat. Voldemort would have to be among those unaccounted for.

Most wizards seemed to want to know as little as possible about Voldemort after his passing.  However, a curious individual like Arthur Weasley (who also had access to Ministry of Magic population records) ought to have been able to work it out.  He presumably shared the information about what house Voldemort had been in with his family, but out of some misplaced sense of propriety did not reveal Voldemort's original name.

Comment: The problem is how would Arthur know Voldemort's real name? He was surprised iirc at the end of Chamber of Secrets to find it out. You're right though that he certainly did look into things, was curious and was against Voldemort in both wars. Some wizards would take the not wanting to know anything about Voldemort to the extreme esp after Harry and Dumbledore insisted he had returned.

Comment: Snape knew Voldemort's real identity. So did Peter Pettigrew. Snape likely would have told Dumbledore when he came over to the good side and Dumbledore would likely have shared that info with the Order.

Answer (score 4):

Arthur and Molly Weasley were in the original Order of the Phoenix. Assuming Dumbledore told the Order that Voldemort was previously known as Tom Riddle (in a know-your-enemy discussion), then it is reasonable to assume that all the Weasley children knew as well, especially after a dozen years of Voldemort's absence.

Comment: The assumption is I believe wrong though. Dumbledore wouldn't have had a reason to tell them and I believe they were alarmed to find out that Ginny was possessed by Voldemort that is Tom Riddle!

Comment: @Pryftan Mr. and Mrs. Weasley were alarmed and horrified to learn their daughter was in mortal peril. I don't think their alarm went as far as learning the secret identity of the perpetrator. In either case, a quote to back up our assertions would be nice...

Comment: Absolutely not. Ginny doesn't know, or she wouldn't have trusted that magic diary. **Neither does Ron**, when they find the diary he remembers the name... only because he had to clean his trophy many times due to an 'accident'. It is funny in retrospect how You-Know-Who's trophy was the one that suffered this fate, though. There's no reason to think that their brothers knew his identity, and probably not even their parents knew it.

Comment: Well since you **asked**: **He had so far avoided mentioning Riddle’s diary — or Ginny. She was standing with her head against Mrs. Weasley’s shoulder, and tears were still coursing silently down her cheeks.[...]** Then: **'What interests me most,' said Dumbledore gently, 'is how Lord Voldemort managed to enchant Ginny, when my sources tell me he is currently in hiding in the forests of Albania.'** Finally: **'W-what’s that? said Mr. Weasley in a stunned voice. 'You-
Know-Who? En-enchant Ginny? But Ginny’s not . . . Ginny hasn’t
been . . . has she?'**

Comment: Which incidentally allows me to amend my original statement: your assumption is wrong; it's no longer a belief.

Comment: @Pryftan Well done. You have me convinced...except there are two small connections that need to be made. First, in the scene you quote, Mr. Weasley is stunned that Voldemort had been active in the current kerfluffle. But is the name "Tom Riddle" mentioned? Or does Dumbledore just jump to using the name of Voldemort? Second, did the diary have the name Tom Riddle engraved on the outside? I don't expect it would have told Ginny Tom Riddle's name; it simply would have said, "Hello, Ginny, my name is Tom and I have a hard time getting people to pay attention to me, too."

Comment: @scott Yes, T.M. Riddle was engraved on the front of the diary. *“Hang on,’ said Ron, who had approached cautiously and was looking over Harry’s shoulder. ‘I know that name … T. M. Riddle got an award for special services to the school fifty years ago.” - Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 13 (The Very Secret Diary)* Ron connected it with a trophy, not the Dark Lord. In addition, Tom introduced himself to Harry as Tom Riddle. *‘Hello, Harry Potter. My name is Tom Riddle. How did you come by my diary?” - Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 13 (The Very Secret Diary)*

Comment: @Pryftan You’re definitely right - neither of the Weasley children who saw the diary thought anything suspicious of the name “Riddle”. Ron only remembered it from a trophy and Ginny was happily writing to him while knowing he was Tom Riddle, until she started realizing she was blacking out and doing things she didn’t intend to. It’s unlikely either of them would have had the reactions they did if they were aware that the Dark Lord was once Tom Riddle.

Comment: @Scott As Miss Bella says (and she should know shouldn't she?) Dumbledore does indeed say Tom Riddle; and later Harry brings up the diary to show how Voldemort could have been manipulating Ginny despite hiding in Albania. **And do you really believe Tom had a hard time getting people to pay attention to him?** Quite the opposite! It wasn't just fear that he had so many people follow him; it wasn't just his ideals either. It was his very character - this is something that all psychopaths are capable of when it comes down to it.

Comment: @Bellatrix Yes. And if it wasn't for perfect Percy perhaps she would have been able to reveal more information but embarrassed with the fact she caught him snogging Penelope (iirc that was her name) and thinking she was going to talk about that... Well things would have quite possibly gone very differently. Then again the Basilisk wouldn't have been slain and this would have changed the plot drastically too. In the end they didn't have any idea it was Voldemort and they were shocked to find out that it *was actually Voldemort!* Thanks for the confirmation Miss Bella!

Comment: @scott Something else just popped into my head. You suggested that Tom Riddle had a hard time with getting people to listen to him, right? Well this is the memory of Riddle talking to Harry in the Chamber: **'If I say it myself, Harry, I’ve always been able to charm the people I needed. So Ginny poured out her soul to me, and her soul happened to be exactly what I wanted. . . . [...]'** And this is only one example. Ginny however wasn't really concerned about anyone except Harry but once she listened to Hermione and started being with others things improved (as it would).

Comment: @Pryftan You make a fair point, but what I was actually suggesting was that Diary-Tom would have pretended to be sympathetic to get Ginny (or anyone) to pour out their soul in order to gain control -- which is exactly what he did do, as you point out.

Comment: @scott Exactly. But he didn't need to pretend that nobody listened to him or paid any attention to him to manipulate someone. All he'd need to do is listen, be sympathetic (even if false) and be cordial. That's what I was trying to say, if you follow me now.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly Voldemort issued a proclamation that mentioned that he was the natural leader of all (or all British?) wizards and gave some justifications for that, possibly including a claim that he had once been the top student in Slytherin, the house that the greatest wizards all came from and the house whose members were the rightful leaders of the wizards.

Thus everyone would know that Voldemort was a former Slytherin student who would have graduated sometime in the previous century or so (since it might be somewhat rare for wizards to live more than about a century after graduating about age 18), without knowing which former Slytherin student it was.

Comment: Ah but the question is: did he? There isn't any canon to suggest he did at this point. What there is though is that he surprised everyone by working at Borgin and Burkes (such a bright student choosing that? But it was a conscious choice with a purpose); then of course Miss Smith was found dead, Hokey had been given a false memory and Riddle disappeared - along with two artefacts. He would resurface years later hardly recognisable after all his transformations. He did later on suggest this though but not until Deathly Hallows. So yes..but no.

Comment: One other thing just crossed my mind that would (ever so slightly) improve your answer (though it depends on if you're answering from the 2000s or the time frame of the story itself) - technically his demise was in 1998 which was last century but the way I interpret your second paragraph is everyone are those who were alive and in the wizarding world at the time - last century - which means that it should be this century. Maybe 'past century'? Just some thoughts that probably don't matter all that much - but FWIW there they are.

Comment: @Pyftan I have changed my answer to make the chronological meaning clearer.

Comment: Fair enough. I honestly can't remember what it was all about and I have far too much going on to really consider it more. Ah, right. Maybe you were referring to my second comment. Yes. I see that now. Better indeed.

Answer (score 1):

## Inferred, from Death Eaters' ties to Slytherin House

The majority of confirmed<sup>(1)</sup> and suspected<sup>(2)</sup> Death Eaters seem to have been former students of Slytherin House, and some came from the most proudly aristocratic levels of magical British society.  These people saw their privileges as rightful, they were determined to increase their power, and they spent their Hogwarts years networking with other Slytherins of similar mind<sup>(3)</sup>.  Whether or not such a collection of ambitious traditionalist bigots was capable of rallying for years around a non-Slytherin leader, the general magical public would have inferred that the Death Eaters could only follow a leader who came from Slytherin.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> IE, those who were convicted (such as the escapees from Azkaban in the [1997 mass breakout](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Azkaban_escapes)) or pardoned (Snape).

<sup>(2)</sup> EG, Lucius Malfoy.

<sup>(3)</sup> EG, [Tom Riddle's core group](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Tom_Riddle%27s_gang).

Answer (score 0):

There's always the "Lee Jordan argument": if all signs point to Slytherin then it's Slytherin. As formulated in Chapter Fourteen of Chamber of Secrets:

> "That's two Gryffindors down, not counting a Gryffindor ghost, one Ravenclaw, and one Hufflepuff," said the Weasley twins' friend Lee Jordan, counting on his fingers. "Haven't any of the teachers noticed that the Slytherins are all safe? Isn't it obvious all this stuff's coming from Slytherin? The Heir of Slytherin, the monster of Slytherin – why don't they just chuck all the Slytherins out?" he roared, to nods and scattered applause.

Similarly, when it comes to Voldemort's house the signs point to Slytherin:

- Virtually all the Death Eaters were from Slytherin.
- Slytherin was known as the house that produced Dark wizards.
- Voldemort and the Death Eaters aligned with Slytherin views about blood purity and Muggle inferiority.
- The Dark Mark's symbol was a serpent, just like Slytherin's symbol.

Of course, it's also possible that someone who knew spread the word.