# How could very few people know the actual identity of Voldemort as Tom Riddle?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Dumbledore says:

> Very few people know that Lord Voldemort was once called Tom Riddle.
>   I taught him myself, fifty years ago, at Hogwarts. He disappeared
>   after leaving the school … travelled far and wide … sank so deeply
>   into the Dark Arts, consorted with the very worst of our kind,
>   underwent so many dangerous, magical transformations, that when he
>   resurfaced as Lord Voldemort, he was barely recognisable. Hardly
>   anyone connected Lord Voldemort with the clever, handsome boy who was
>   once Head Boy here.

Also we know that everyone knows that Voldemort was in Slytherin. At least when Ron mentions this

> “Gryffindor,” said Ron. Gloom seemed to be settling on him again. “Mum
>   and Dad were in it, too. I don’t know what they’ll say if I’m not. I
>   don’t suppose Ravenclaw would be too bad, but imagine if they put me
>   in Slytherin.”
>
> “That’s the House Vol-, I mean, You-Know-Who was in?”
>
> “Yeah,” said Ron. He flopped back into his seat, looking depressed.

Then how do very few people know the real identity of the Voldemort as Tom Riddle, surely people would have searched and found out this once he disappeared. Actually everyone should know this considering Voldemort is really famous among wizards.

Comment: Related: [Was Voldemort's secret identity always known to the Ministry of Magic? Was it ever secret?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22840), [Who else knew that Lord Voldemort was Tom Marvolo Riddle?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26741), [How can Ron know that Voldemort was in Slytherin if nobody knows his real identity?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186644)

Comment: It seems likely that everybody simply *assumes* that Voldemort was in Slytherin, and it is only by coincidence that they are right.

Comment: Because anagrams are _hard_, you know?